# Shared element when using startActivityForResult

Tags: android, android-intent, shared-element-transition, activity-transition

I have an app with two `activities`, where the second functions as an image "picker" and delivers some information to the first, so that an `ImageView` can be updated accordingly.

For this, I'm calling the second `activity` through `startActivityForResult()`, and updating the `ImageView` according to information received on `onActivityResult()`.

The problem arises when I try to animate a shared element between the picker and the main `Activity`: it seems like the transition "snapshots" the first `Activity`, and even if the `ImageView` is updated as soon as the `Activity` resumes, the transition animation will "flicker" an older version of the `View` before showing the current version.

Here's an example app I made to illustrate what I'm talking about:

[image: Visual description of the bug]

**What would be the best way to implement this animation seamlessly? Should another approach be used?**

Here's the code used for the example:

Main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView mainImageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Main Activity");

        mainImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PickerActivity.class);
                ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.
                        makeSceneTransitionAnimation(MainActivity.this, mainImageView, "shape_transition");
                startActivityForResult(intent, 1, options.toBundle());
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        int shapeNumber = intent.getIntExtra("shape_number", -1);

        switch (shapeNumber) {
            case 1:
                mainImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.blue);
                break;
            case 2:
                mainImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.green);
                break;
            default:
                //something else
                break;
        }


    }
}
```

Picker Activity:

```
public class PickerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView blueImageView;
    ImageView greenImageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_picker);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Picker Activity");

        blueImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

        blueImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                blueImageView.setTransitionName("shape_transition");
                Intent intent = new Intent(PickerActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("shape_number", 1);
                setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                finishAfterTransition();
            }
        });

        greenImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);

        greenImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                greenImageView.setTransitionName("shape_transition");
                Intent intent = new Intent(PickerActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("shape_number", 2);
                setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                finishAfterTransition();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Main Activity xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="demonstration.sharedelementproblemexample.MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="128dp"
        android:layout_height="128dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:transitionName="shape_transition"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:src="@drawable/red" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Pick"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Picker Activity xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="demonstration.sharedelementproblemexample.PickerActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="128dp"
        android:layout_height="128dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:src="@drawable/blue" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="128dp"
        android:layout_height="128dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:src="@drawable/green"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView2" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While working on another project, I found a way to prevent this flickering from happening.

In the first Activity (the one that sent the request), instead of updating the view that initially transitioned through the `onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent)` method, you should override `onActivityReenter(int resultCode, Intent data)` and update the view from there.

This method is called before the transition animation begins, and you still have access to information from the other `Activity` through the `Intent` parameter.

Here's the same example app using this solution:

[image: picture showing the fix]

And here's the overriden method:

```
@Override
public void onActivityReenter(int resultCode, Intent data) {
    int shapeNumber = data.getIntExtra("shape_number", -1);

    switch (shapeNumber) {
        case 1:
            mainImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.blue);
            break;
        case 2:
            mainImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.green);
            break;
        default:
            //something else
            break;
    }
    super.onActivityReenter(resultCode, data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The main issue is that it should work flawlessly even when the user doesn't select either of the images (simply presses back). I couldn't really figure out any elegant way to accomplish this (since, we were already using `onActivityResult()`). However, I do have a [pretty dirty] hack that should work.

What we can do is have a very small `AlphaAnimation` (10 ms or so) and fade the root `ViewGroup` of the `Activity` in and out on `onResume()` and `onPause()` respectively. For this to work flawlessly (read without flickr) the initial visibility  of the `ViewGroup` should be `View.INVISIBLE`. This should also be set when the fade-out animation ends (via `AnimationListener`).

With this setup we're basically purchasing time for ourselves so we can setup our `ImageView` instance appropriately. It is of course a hack at the end of the day and I'd love to hear any other valid answers. Nice question!